# Get pixel coordinates from Brute Force Matching in OpenCV Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, matching

I would like to get pixel coordinates of query and train image using OpenCV in Python.

The code is:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img1 = cv2.imread('qimg.png',0)          # queryImage
img2 = cv2.imread('timg.png',0)          # trainImage

# Initiate SIFT detector
orb = cv2.ORB()

# find the keypoints and descriptors with SIFT
kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(img2,None)

# create BFMatcher object
bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)

# Match descriptors.
matches = bf.match(des1,des2)
```

I want to get the pixel coordinates from each `DMatch` object.

How do I do that?

Comment: The code is - `#code` , The problem is - `?????`

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what the problem is?

Comment: 'matches' will supply a list of DMatch objects. I want to get pixel coordinates of each of the DMatch objects for query image and train image. Basically I want to  know which part of image is matched with which part of train image is matched with which part of query image.

Comment: I want to know where is a predefined part of image is found in qimg in terms of pixel coordinates

Answer (score -1):

You can do it using commands:

```
src_pts = np.float32([ kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in matches ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
dst_pts = np.float32([ kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in matches ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
```

Where

- `m.trainIdx` - Index of the descriptor in train descriptors and
- `m.queryIdx` - Index of the descriptor in query descriptors